# If, IsError, Then Loop Comparing 4 Columns of Cells

Tags: vba, excel, string-matching

[image]Straight to the point:

I am trying to match A2 on sheet "PRD" to A2 on sheet "CRD", if this is a match I want to compare B2 on sheet PRD to B2 on sheet CRD and then A3 same thing on and on to the end of the range. If there is no match between cells in column A I am trying to copy the whole row to a third sheet, if there is a match between cells in A but there is not a match between cells in B I am trying to copy the row to a third sheet.

I am stuck, I think after hours of looking at the code and Googling, not being able to check column B... I seem to be able to check, copy and paste cells that do not match contents in column A fine.

I hope I am asking the right questions and am clear, thanks for any help!!

```
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim r3 As Range
Dim r4 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

'CRD date
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CRD")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r1 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
End With

'CRD quantity
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CRD")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r3 = .Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
End With

'PRD date
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PRD")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r2 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
End With

'PRD quantity
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PRD")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r4 = .Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
End With

'match PRD date to CRD date: output "Found" for record, or copy/paste onto report page
Range("A2").Select
For Each cell In r1
    If IsError(Application.Match(cell, r2, 0)) Then
    'select active cell's row and copy, pasting in report page
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("CRD").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'if no error check quantity(B) of same cell, if match continue, if no match copy
    ElseIf IsError(Application.Match(r3, r4, 0)) Then
        For Each cell2 In r3
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("CRD").Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next
    Else
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825676/vba-nested-if-then-else-loop-that-copies-non-matching-entries/49826052?noredirect=1#comment86669340_49826052 Here is a link to a working solution for this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code relies too much on `Select`, `ActiveCell`, `Selection` and `Activate`, you should avoid all these `Select`ing and use fully qualified objects instead.

See the code below, and explanations inside the code's comments.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Match2Columns()

Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim r3 As Range
Dim r4 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

'CRD date
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CRD")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r1 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
End With

'CRD quantity
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CRD")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r3 = .Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
End With

'PRD date
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PRD")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r2 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
End With

'PRD quantity
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PRD")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r4 = .Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
End With

Dim PasteRow As Long ' row to paste at "sheet1"

'match PRD date to CRD date: output "Found" for record, or copy/paste onto report page
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CRD") ' <-- make sure you are looping and copying from "CRD" sheet
    For Each cell In r1
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell, r2, 0)) Then
            ' select active cell's row and copy, pasting in report page
            .Rows(cell.Row).Copy

            ' get last empty row and add 1 row where to paste
            PasteRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

            ' paste action
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'if no error check quantity(B) of same cell, if match continue, if no match copy
        ElseIf IsError(Application.Match(r3, r4, 0)) Then
            For Each cell2 In r3
                ' select active cell's row and copy, pasting in report page
                .Rows(cell2.Row).Copy

                ' get last empty row and add 1 row where to paste
                PasteRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

                ' paste action
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Next cell2
        Else
            ' you are doing nothing here, not sure why you need it ???
        End If
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code revision, and thank you for the explanations they really did help me understand why my code was so confusing and where I made errors. It seems logical that it checks A2 then B2 between both sheets and then moves onto A3 B3 etc from the code you gave me, and my own, but it does not seem to be doing that, it seems to only be checking A column and finding the no matches. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewCaprario can you describe again what you want to do ? check column A, and what other column , if one matches or another what needs to be copied ? you can add **Edit 1** at the bottom of your post trying to explain, Maybe add a screen-shot with some examples

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think the code I started with and the edits you made should do what I need it to, that's why I am stuck! It should be check cell one, if does not match do x, if match check cell two, if does not match do x, if match move to next row so on and so forth.